# PySide (Qt): How to set background color of button's tooltip?

Tags: python, qt, colors, stylesheet, pyside

I've just got a fast question:

How to set a color  of button's tooltip?

#### code

```
    btnExample = QtGui.QPushButton('Example button', self)
    btnExample.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 255, 0)")
    btnExample.clicked.connect(function_of_button)
    btnExample.setToolTip('Animated splines toolkit') # I'd like to change colors here
```

It's PySide, Python, I've got light gray text on button, so the text on tooltip is also light.
I've got to change it's background to black

Comment: See this answer for how to do it with a Stylesheet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17900401/1427800

Comment: I've been searching, sorry I've missed that! Thank You.